# Rsync files from machine A to standalone machine B

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to rsync files from machine A to a standalone machine B.  At present there should not be any deleted files on the source, machine A. The changed files would be copied to a separate folder and moved to the standalone system, machine B via a DVD or hard drive depending on the size of the data. Then the changed files would be rsynced to the same location on the standalone system.

Comment: So what is your question?  What is preventing you from doing that?  What have you tried so far, what errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you can't directly access to the B, so that you will use an external disk or DVD to indirectly rsync B from A.

I think you shouldn't use a ROM like DVD but an external drive.

So you have 3 systems: A, B, and HDD (let's call it so)

Suppose you mount HDD at /mnt/HDD in both A and B. And the files are rsynced to the root of HDD. The source directory at A is /source and destination directory at B is /dest.

First you mount HDD on A and rsync A to HDD:

```
rsync -avH --delete-after /source/ /mnt/HDD/
```

After that you unmount HDD from A and mount at B. And rsync there:

```
rsync -avH --delete-after /mnt/HDD/ /dest/
```

Note that --delete-after is there to delete files from the destination if they are deleted from the source, not to delete rsyned files from the source.

For the arguments: a creates a full backup, v for verbose and H for hardlinks (so that hardlinked files do not occupy multiple spaces on the disk)

You can also add --checksum argument if you want to check the integrity of files for rsyncing (even though the size and time signatures might be the same, the files may be corrupted).

If your point is just to copy the changed files to HDD, that would not be a good idea for rsyncing. How then you can treat files deleted from A? ANd how can you track changed files (you have to compare two trees for that in each step).